# switch application directly freeze for a few seconds

Tags: 20.04, gnome, unity, shortcut-keys, freeze

I am using ubuntu 20.04 with key board shortcut set for switch window directly(done in settings), it works.
However after I pressed the shortcut the new window pops up with an orange border , the new window freezes for aroud 2 seconds ,nothing could be done on the new window for the 2 seconds until the orange border disappears .
However on ubuntu 16 with standard gnome 36 ,the new window is accessible immediately without this annoying border and freeze .

Is this a redicoulously annoying feature or some kind of bugs?
Could the freeze period being reduced ,orange boarder removed?

The freeze seems to occur only for single shortcut like pause or printscreen, when using more dual key combinations as the shortcut like ctrl+pause or ctrl+printscreen ,there is no such freeze

os version
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"

Comment: the freeze seems to occur when using one key shortcut like pause, when using key combinations like ctrl+pause ,there is no such lag/freeze/

Comment: Add relevant information to the question: comments may disappear and may not be read. However, your comment indicates the solution is simple: do not use the shortcut "pause" for this.